# How to make a double click program from .java files?

Tags: java, javac

No matter which search terms I use, every tutorial tells me that I can make java programs by using `javac` to convert my .java files to .class files. And then I can use the command prompt to invoke the program. But that's not what I have seen. Usually I just double click something. Not a .java, not a .class file, it's just ... there's no file extension. It's a purple diamond on Linux which you can double click, and the java program starts. The tutorials always end at "use javac, then call java". Sorry for this stupid question.

Comment: double click on something !!!  Is it an executable jar file ?

Comment: On Windows you can create bat file that will start java. And then you will be able to run it with double-click

Comment: no I don't mean executable jar. I mean that purple diamond symbol on ubuntu. I cannot find it on google. I mean just a double click which starts the java program. There is no file extension. like eclipse on ubuntu.

Comment: I found a website with the symbol. It's the second screenshot where he right clicks the symbol and a dropdown appears ("run" ...choices ecetera): http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/

Comment: This is an IDE (Eclipse in this case) program that allows to conveniently develop and run Java programs. But to make your own java program to be executed with double-click you need executable jar and a starter (bat file on Windows and Shell (?) script on Ubuntu)

Comment: ok I got that, but then what is that purple diamond symbol?